# jQuery replace element with textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to replace a p tag with a textbox using jQuery. What I have tried isn't working.

Comment: Are you trying to do in-place editing by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<p> Some text.. </p>


$('p').dblclick(function(){
    var textArea = $('<textarea />')
    var oldText = $(this).text();

    $(this).replaceWith(textArea);
    textArea.val(oldText);
});​
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/msRu6/).

On focusout, you can read the new value (or old) and set it back within a `p` tag.

See that example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/msRu6/1/)

Comment: I have given you 10 myself for 2 of your questions. But no hurry as long as you do, someday.

Comment: Can we again replace this textarea text with label which we clicked after editing @RobinMaben

Comment: Yes. Then instead of `replace` we need to use `detach()` and `append`. I shall post and example shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

API: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/  **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yuuhr/

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided
>   new content.

Please let me know if I missed anything or provide full html

Hope this helps

**code**

```
$('p').replaceWith('<textarea id="foohulk"/>')
```

Comment: Thank you i tried the same thig except that i did not specify textarea i gave the id of textarea in that place

Comment: @SravanL no worries, feel free to use the demo `:)`